# Grab Row Where Value is True in One of the Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table on my SQL Server 2016:

```
InvoiceNumber AutoPay        PaymentPlan
1234         Disabled          Active 
5678         Inactive           Completed
9123         Never Set Up       NULL
3456         Active             Cancelled
```

I'm trying to find each Invoice Number that has an AutoPay or PaymentPlan on the account.

As long as one of the columns is says Active or Completed, I want my query to display that row.

Result:

```
    InvoiceNumber     AutoPay        PaymentPlan
     1234             Disabled          Active
     5678             Inactive          Completed
     3456             Active             Cancelled
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: `select InvoiceNumber, AutoPay, PaymentPlan from your_table where AutoPay in ('Active', 'Completed') or PaymentPlan in ('Active', 'Completed')`

Comment: In my WHERE statement I tried the following:

(AutoPay is not null OR AutoPay not like '%Disabled%' OR AutoPay <> 'Never Set Up' OR AutoPAy not like '%Inactive%') AND (PaymentPlan is not null OR PaymentPlan not like '%Cancelled%' OR PaymentPlan <> 'None')

Comment: you know the possible values of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tablename
where paymentplan IN ('Active','Completed') or autopay IN ('Active','Completed')
```

Comment: This is incorrect since you can't be certain those are the only values in those two columns

Comment: Your edit is closer, but still needs to check `AutoPay`

Answer (score 1):

i think below will work

According to your description you need below  condition in your query

```
select t.* from  t
    where AutoPay IN ('Active','Completed') or
    PaymentPlan in ('Active', 'Completed')
```

Comment: Why do you use "Never Set Up"?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten look his sample data  there AutoPay column values shown all except never set up

Comment: @OfirWinegarten but thanks in that case i need to use and operator

Comment: But thats not because of "Never Set Up". Read the question, The OP specifies exactly what he needs

Comment: yap i used IN ('Active','Completed') or autopay IN ('Active','Completed') 1st but later his output i changed

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yap true

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber
FROM myTable
WHERE AutoPay IN ('Active','Completed') OR PaymentPlan IN ('Active','Completed')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Invoice_Table]
WHERE [AutoPay] IN ('Active','Completed') OR [PaymentPlan] IN ('Active','Completed')
ORDER BY  [InvoiceNumber]
```

That is what I would use but I don't know the name of your table so swap that out in the FROM line.

Cheers

Comment: Why `AutoPay` is checked only for "Active"?

Comment: I was looking at the example data when I wrote the query and missed the part in the question where it said that 'completed' is a possible condition for autopay